# How to query using unique document id in Firestore from flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have multiple documents containing different worker name and their details and instead of giving an auto I'd I have assigned a unique id like 'id_1', 'id_2' and so on to each documents. Now my question is how to access these different documents and its particular fields like worker name and address and display it using a text widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u want to get all the documents at once then u can use :

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore().collection('Workers').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data != null) {
      // Here u will get list of document snapshots
      final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data.documents;
      // now u can access each document by simply specifying its number
      // u can also use list view to display every one of them
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) => Text(documents[index].data['name']),
      );
    } else {
      // Show loading indicator here
    }
  },
);
```

If u want to get particular document details (if u have the document id) then u can use :

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> _getDocument(String documentName) async {
   return await Firestore().collection('Workers').document(documentName).get();
 }
```

now u can access fields by there name e.g.

```
documentSnapshot.data['Name']
```

i hope this help :)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply, can you help(explain) with the second part of your answer-"If u want to get particular document details (if u have the document id) then u can use :" after this...    Can you explain or how can I use it inside a widget or in a different dart file...

Comment: just use future builder for that. copy & paste the method give document name & collection name then u r good to go

Answer (score 2):

you can get the document snapshot using

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('yourCollection').document('docId').get();
```

you can access it by simply calling

```
documentSnapshot.data['yourField'];
```