# How can I convert the documents in a Firebase Collection into a Map (in Flutter)?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

As the title says it. I really can't visualize differences between each of the snapshot methods stated by past questions. I keep getting null values when using snapshots and StreamBuilders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create model like this:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class EmployeeData {
  final DocumentReference reference;
  String address;
  String designation;

  EmployeeData.data(
     this.reference, [
     this.address,
     this.designation,
 ]);

 factory EmployeeData.from(DocumentSnapshot document) => EmployeeData.data(
    document.reference,
    document.data['Address'],
    document.data['Designation'],
  );

 void save() {
  reference.setData(toMap());
 }

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  return {
  'address': address,
  'designation': designation,
 };
 }
}
```

then pass document in it like this :

```
Map map = EmployeeData.from(snapshot).toMap()
```

Comment: Thanks. But where should I pass the last statement in the code?

Comment: maybe in `StreamBuilder` or such where u can access snapshot of data

Comment: checkout this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544068/how-to-query-using-unique-document-id-in-firestore-from-flutter/60544756#60544756

Comment: Thanks a lot! The solution in the second link was what I was looking for. Works perfectly now, and I'm a step closer to understanding streams.